# On reloading page, MySQL query(UPDATE Query) is being execute on each reload

Tags: php, mysql, reload, page-refresh

On reloading page, MySQL query(UPDATE Query) is being execute on each reload. I want execution of query only for one time. Please suggest me some solution. Thank You.

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: Use session to store info that query is executed. So always check on session...is it already executed or not.

Comment: For the first time load please add a session counter variable and for next url refresh check that session variable have a value 1 or not. If it has a value then please do not execute query.

Comment: Another alternative would be to redirect the user from the page handling the update to another page.

Comment: Each time you do any save or update on submit button just redirect the page after operation. If you remain in that page then each refresh will update or save data.

Comment: for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) { $newStoke = $fet[$j]['pro_stoke'] - $pro_qnt[$j]; $id = $fet[$j]['pro_id']; $str = "update products set pro_stoke='$newStoke' where pro_id='$id'"; $qry = mysql_query($str);}

Answer (score 0):

in your update query also ad session , and check before execute  the  query check the session value is null or not . if null then execute

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION["reload"] = "1";

    ?>
```

before query

```
if($_SESSION['reload'] !=''){
  //perform update query operation
}
```

Comment: for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {
    $newStoke = $fet[$j]['pro_stoke'] - $pro_qnt[$j];
    $id = $fet[$j]['pro_id'];
    $str = "update products set pro_stoke='$newStoke' where pro_id='$id'";
    $qry = mysql_query($str);

Comment: session_start();
for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {

if($_SESSION['reload'] !=''){

 $newStoke = $fet[$j]['pro_stoke'] - $pro_qnt[$j]; $id = $fet[$j]['pro_id'];
 
 $str = "update products set pro_stoke='$newStoke' where pro_id='$id'"; 
 
 }else{

    $_SESSION["reload"] = "1";
 }
 
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

try to set cookie or session after first execution ,  and before execution the query do check if cookie or session already set , If not then execute.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
  session_start();
  
  if (!isset($_SESSION['loaded']) {
    
    //you can process your update
    //and create the session key "loaded"
    $_SESSION['loaded'] = 1;

  } else {
  
    //the session already exist, you can do other things

  }
?>
```

But you must destroy this session somewhere in your application.